# NetBeans7.4 IDE under oracle

Tags: php, oracle, netbeans, oracle11g

i need help to connect oracle 11g to netbeans 7.4
i have been downloaded ojdbc6.jar,getting this following error**"cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:oci:localhost:1521:xe using oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver(no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path)"**
i can connect with Sql deveoper.

Comment: Which jdk version that you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in error you need `ocijdbc12` you can find those with oracle instant client download. You also need to add `oci` to path also.